# Passing function char argument returns error

Tags: c, function, pointers, char

I'm new to C programming and trying to figure out why I'm getting an error trying to pass the char variable into the function

```
char cmd[100];
getLine(&cmd, &line);
```

function declaration:

```
int getLine(char *cmdl, char *str)
```

Error:

```
cannot convert char (*)[100] to char* for argument 1 to int getLine(char*, char*)
```

Comment: "the char variable" - nah, the `char [100]` variable.

Comment: Also, [obligatory link about pointers vs. arrays.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions argument types is a `char *`. So you don't need to use `&cmd`. Just using `cmd` will pass the base address of that array.

So either you call the function like:

```
getLine(cmd, &line);
```

or change the function declaration like:

```
int getLine(char **cmdl, char *str)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Midhun MP already said, the Array is already passed as a pointer/reference, so no need to reference it in the function call.